# Assign sum of column to one date in another column if criteria is met

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=4b1bfb7eb9b7be0a65d62b3ac8f3c0e6)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    customerID VARCHAR(255),
    sales_date DATE,
    sales_volume INT,
    annual_unqiue_count INT
);

INSERT INTO sales
(customerID, sales_date, sales_volume, annual_unqiue_count)
VALUES 
("Customer_01", "2020-03-01", "600", "1"),
("Customer_01", "2020-03-25", "315", "0"),

("Customer_02", "2020-03-18", "208", "1"),
("Customer_02", "2020-07-25", "140", "0"),

("Customer_03", "2020-10-18", "400", "1"),
("Customer_03", "2020-12-06", "500", "0"),
("Customer_03", "2020-12-18", "438", "0"),
("Customer_03", "2020-12-25", "917", "0");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
customerID      sales_date   SUM(annual_unqiue_count)   SUM(sales_volume)
Customer_01     2020-03-01              1                    915    (=600+315)
Customer_01     2020-03-25              0                    0
Customer_02     2020-03-18              1                    348    (=208+140)
Customer_02     2020-07-25              0                    0
Customer_03     2020-10-18              1                    2255   (=400+500+438+917)
Customer_03     2020-12-06              0                    0
Customer_03     2020-12-18              0                    0 
Customer_03     2020-12-25              0                    0
```

---

In the result I want to **assign** the `SUM(sales_volume)` per `customer` to the `sales_date` which has an `annual_unqiue_count <> 0`.

So far I tried to go with this query but could not make it work:

```
SELECT
customerID,
sales_date,
SUM(annual_unqiue_count),
SUM(sales_volume)
FROM sales
GROUP BY 1,2
HAVING SUM(annual_unqiue_count) <> 0;
```

What do I need to change to get the expected result?

Comment: Does only one row per `customerID` have `annual_unqiue_count<>0`? if not - what is desired output? if true - how does according constraint looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want window functions:

```
select s.*,
       (case when annual_unqiue_count <> 0
             then sum(sales_volume) over (partition by customerId)
             else 0
        end) as sales_volume
from sales s;
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=62403755700fcca074b8ab75a3c6ab36